# SharePoint 2013: Subsite removal on ParentSite on caused entire collection deletion

Tags: site-collection, sub-site, site-deletion

I am a fairly 'green' SharePoint collection admin.  I was going through and removing old/unused subsites within my collection.  When I navigated to my parent 'site contents' and removed a few subsites that appeared to be unused, my entire SiteCollection was removed...and now I get a "webpage cannot be found" error.

I contacted my server FARM, I know they are able to restore my site collection, but i just want to know what i did wrong!

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the top site in a Site Collection, the Site Collection will also be deleted. The message a just a little different, so this is easy to do.

**Delete a subsite:**

[image]

**Delete the top level site:** (note the extra warning text)

[image]

Your farm admins can recover the top level site. Additional subsites can be recovered from the Recycle Bin of the recovered Site Collection.